# RegEx - finding group at the end of the line

Tags: java, regex

Expression does not match if it is located at the end of the line:

```
(\b%%\b([^%])*\b%%\b)
```

test string:

```
djwk%%text%%doqdojd%%text.text.text%%kjwldjdflkljwfe%%body.text.text%%
```

as result:

```
djwk_doqdojd_kjwldjdflkljwfe%%body.text.text%%
```

but the last one is missed (tested [via](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/))

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to have a result like:

```
djwk_doqdojd_kjwldjdflkljwfe_
```

Then, just try the follow regex:

```
(\b%%\b([^%])*\b%%)
```

**Explanation:**

The final "\b" on the regex you have provided, forces that the character "%%" can't be the last element on the target string.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers, Nikolas.

Comment: Strange... it works... but why this happens? \b does not detect eol?

Comment: Actually, not really... "\b" matches [a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). So as you were specifying that it must have one success match after the double "%", it was not matching the one in the end of the string passed. I would suggest you take a look at the [regex101](https://regex101.com), there you can understand each part of your regex. Cheers